# Trouble Saving and Reading Static Object Array to NSDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I currently have the following `Codable`data structures:

```
//Models for Data Handling
struct EventModel: Codable {
    let id: UUID
    let eventName: String
    let fromTime, toTime: Date
    let fromTimeString, toTimeString: String
    let color: Color
    init(id: UUID = .init(),
         eventName: String,
         fromTime: Date,
         toTime: Date,
         fromTimeString: String,
         toTimeString: String,
         color: Color) {
        self.id = id
        self.eventName = eventName
        self.fromTime = fromTime
        self.toTime = toTime
        self.fromTimeString = fromTimeString
        self.toTimeString = toTimeString
        self.color = color
    }
}

struct Color: Codable {
    let (r,g,b,a): (CGFloat,CGFloat,CGFloat,CGFloat)
    var color: UIColor { UIColor.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a) }
}
```

I also have the following `Codable` object array in the `EventData` class:

```
//EventData class with EventDataArray
class EventData: Codable {
    
    static var EventDataArray: [EventModel] = []
    
}
```

Right now, I have a save button that triggers the following. It creates an instance of the class `EventData` and saves it to NSUserDefaults. Since the array is static, all instances should (in theory) hold the same values. The parameters I used (text, fromTime, etc.) were declared previously in the `@IBAction` function and were omitted for brevity.

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {

            //initialize object
            let currentEvent = EventModel(eventName: text, fromTime: fromTime, toTime: toTime, fromTimeString: fromTimeString, toTimeString: toTimeString, color: convertedColor)
        
            //append to data model
            EventData.EventDataArray.append(currentEvent)
            
            //write to NSUserDefaults
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(currentEvent) {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "SavedEventData")
            }
}
```

This is what I'm confused on. How do I repopulate the array using the static array in the saved data instance?

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let savedEventData = defaults.object(forKey: "SavedEventData") as? Data {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let loadedEventData = try? decoder.decode(EventData.self, from: savedEventData) {
            //I'm confused on what to do here.
            }
        }
```

I am unable to call the `EventDataArray` from the instance `loadedEventData`, and get this error when trying to do so `Static member 'EventDataArray' cannot be used on instance of type 'EventData'` I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Result in error? What error? How did you saved your data in UserDefaults? Did you used a JSONEncoder? Alsoe, `xcdatamodel` is more for CoreData (which isn't your case).

Comment: "Codable + UserDefaults" in your favorite SEO: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-load-and-save-a-struct-in-userdefaults-using-codable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876420/save-struct-to-userdefaults https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697001/saving-a-codable-struct-to-userdefaults-with-swift What went wrong with that code?

Comment: @Larme I used those links and updated my question above

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Save:
    var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: 
    EventDataArray)
    userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "EventDataArray")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

Data Read:
    let decoded  = userDefaults.data(forKey: "EventDataArray")
    let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) 
    as! [EventDataArray]
```

You get the more answers to this link [Save custom objects into NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct UserInfo: Codable {
    var name: String
    var emailId: String
    var dob: String
    var city: String
    var study: String
}
```

- **save** data to **UserDefault**

  ```
  if let userInfo = try? JSONEncoder.encode(self.UserInfo) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(userInfo, forKey: "UserInfo")  }
  ```
- **retrive** data from **UserDefault**

  ```
   if let retriveData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserInfo") as? Data {
   if let userdata = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserInfo.self, from: retriveData) {
       print(userDetails)
   }}
  ```